# sql select the product with most users

Tags: mysql, sql

users:

```
uid int(11) - userid(primary key, auto_increment)
name varchar(255)
pass varchar(64)
created int(11)
```

projects:

```
pid int(11) .....
name varchar(150)
description varchar(255)
created int(11)
```

users_projects:

```
uid int(11) - user id
pid int(11) - product id
```

How can i select the project with the most ussers assigned to it?

sql query.

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `SQL Server`? `MySQL`? `Oracle`? `DB2`? etc.. and define **product with most users**

Comment: how about the second question? how do you know that a product has most users? and i guess you mean project right?\

Comment: well in the users_projects we have the id of the user and the id of the project i want to extract the project with the most users like maybe i have 10 users with the same project and i want to show that

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like this:

```
select p.pid, 
  p.name,
  up.TotalUsers
from projects p
inner join
(
  select pid, count(uid) TotalUsers
  from users_projects
  group by pid
) up
  on p.pid = up.pid
order by TotalUsers Desc
-- limit 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2da4a/17)

This will return the list of all projects and a count of the Total Users per project.  If you want to return the project will the most users, then you will include the `limit 1` that is commented out.

If you have more than one `project` that has the same number of users, then you would want to use something similar to this:

```
select p.pid, 
  p.name,
  up.TotalUsers
from projects p
inner join
(
  select pid, count(uid) TotalUsers
  from users_projects
  group by pid
) up
  on p.pid = up.pid
where totalusers = (select count(*) Total
                    from users_projects
                    group by pid
                    order by total desc
                    limit 1)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2da4a/16)

Thanks [@JW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811854/sql-select-the-product-with-most-users/14812131#14812131) for the Fiddle

Answer (score 1):

The following query will include multiple projects having the same number of users and happens to be the most number of users.

```
SELECT  a.name userName, c.name ProjectName
FROM    users a
        INNER JOIN users_projects b
            ON a.uid = b.uid
        INNER JOIN projects c
            ON b.pid = c.pid
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  pid, COUNT(*) totalCount
            FROM    users_projects
            GROUP   BY pid
            HAVING  COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) x 
                                FROM users_projects 
                                GROUP BY pid 
                                ORDER BY x DESC 
                                LIMIT 1)
        ) d ON b.pid = d.pid
ORDER   BY a.Name ASC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*with duplicate project*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2da4a/8)
- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9948d/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for only one project, the following is the fastest way:

```
select project_id, count(*) as NumUsers
from user_projects
group by project_id
order by count(*) desc
limit 1
```

(I am assuming that "product" = "project").